# Ordering the output of a loop by a custom field containing a datestamp

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, loops

I'm using a custom field that stores the timestamp of a date entered by the user. I want to display posts sorted by that custom date, but they refuse to order by custom field.

Here I register the custom field using this custom meta boxes tool - https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress

```
// the prefix is _cmb_
array(
    'name' => 'Start Time',
    'id'   => $prefix . 'start_time',
    'type' => 'text_datetime_timestamp',
),
```

Then I use WP_Query to loop through the posts with the following arguments:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'talks',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => '_cmb_start_time',
  'order' => 'ASC'
); // show talks ordered by start time

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This prints out the posts in the order they were added and not in the order of the custom field date.

---

## Update

I was also trying to filter by another custom field type "room" with a value equal to "room 1":

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'talks',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby' => '_cmb_start_time',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_key' => 'room',
  'meta_value' => 'room 1'
);
```

### Solution:

With @joebuckle 's solution I ended up with this version that works great:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'talks',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_key' => '_cmb_start_time',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'room',
      'value' => 'room 1',
      'compare' => '='
    )
  ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this instead (ref [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters))

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'talks',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => '_cmb_start_time',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
); // show talks ordered by start time

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```